# RavenDB Complex Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I am trying to learn RavenDB by replacing my RDBMS in a project that I've already worked on so that I'm using it in a real situation.  I've come to a standstill while trying to create the database, and I'd love to know the best way to model this in a document database.  Every possibility I come up with either ends up looking like a relational database or ends up repeating vasts amount of information.  Repeating the information in the database isn't a big deal, but keeping it all up to date when changes occur would be.

I'm hoping that I'm stuck in SQL mode and I'm just completely unable to see an obvious answer.

Here are the basic objects I need to record data for:
-Event
-Person
-Organization
-Cabin

Simple Requirements:
-A **person** can be a part of multiple **organizations**.
-An **organization** can have many members (**people**).
-A **person** can attend multiple **events**.
-An **event** has many **people** that attend.
-Some details about a cabin may change depending on the event (e.g. Accommodations).

Complex Requirements:
-I need to be able to reserve **cabins** for an **event** so that a single cabin is not used by two events at once. (with RDBMS I would just create an "EventCabins" table).
-I need to be able to record which **people** are attending an **event**.  People attending an event will have information associated with them that is not part of Person or Event.
-I need to be able to record which **organizations** are attending an **event**. Organizations attending will have information associated with them that is not part of Organization or Event.
-I need to be able to record which **People** are assigned to which **cabins** in a particular event.
-I need to be able to record which **People** are attending a particular event as a part of an **organization** (it's not required to attend as a part of an organization).  Even though a person can belong to more than one organization, he/she can only attend as a part of one of those organizations for a particular event.  He/she might attend as a part of a different organization for another event.
-In the program, the user will be looking at only one event at a time.  In that event, the user can look at attenders grouped by cabin or grouped by organization.

It seems obvious that I will need separate collections for **Events**, **People**, **Organizations**, and **Cabins**.  Fulfilling the complex requirements above is where I hit the wall.

Do I put **Attenders** inside the **Event** collection? If so, then what do I do with  Cabins and Organizations?

Do I create a separate collection for Attenders?  If so, then there will be 4 different related collections that I will need to store Ids for and query at various times (Organizations, Cabins, Events, People).  This seems opposite of the document database approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should just use a relational database for this project.
If you want to use RavenDB I would suggest to use completely separated collections for all of these objects, but keeping references to other documents. Then you could query database using .Include functionality. And the best way - to create map/reduce indecies for all of the possible cases, like an index returning object for Event filled with all of invited people.